# Is there a way of filling an Enum dynamically from a data base table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I want to create an enum for choosing possibilities but those possibilities may change. So in order to be able to make changes easily I want those possibilities to be stored in and managed thru a data base table. Is there a way of filling an enum dynamically from a data base table?
Thank you, Dov.

Comment: If they change so often wonder how are they qualified to be an `Enum` ?

Comment: They don't change that often but when they do it's seems easier and more efficient to change in the data base thru a form for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of this possibility. However, why dont you use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) ??

Comment: The advantage of enum is that it can be placed in a way that it can be used throughout the whole application. This is important to me especially because I'm working in web and I don't want to have to constantly use session or other state objects or constantly query the data base so that datails be available to different parts of the application.

Comment: @Dov Miller: You do not have to use session or any other state variables here. Depending on the database to get your enumuration or dictionary as I am suggesting means you have to load the data from the database everytime you need it. And who said that you can not use Dictionary from your whole application ??

Comment: I wanted to know if there's a way of loading the data once from the database at the beginning of a session and not having to do so afterwards every time the data is needed. Thank you

Comment: What I wanted to know is if there's a way of avoiding that. Thank you

Comment: @Dov Miller: Data need to be saved somewhere if dont need to load it from database each and everytime you want to use it...

Comment: That session option I knew of and was trying to find an option that didn't need it. I understand from you and previus answers that it's not possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the enum to automatically change (add/remove enum contants) to reflect the values in your database table? If so, no, that is not possible. Enumerations are just a set of named integer constants. You have to change the enum manually and recompile your assembly.

Comment: Yes. That's my intention. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you have two options:

1. Use `CodeDom` to construct the enum :
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx
2. Write the enum source code to a textfile and compile it dynamicaly to an assembly.

Nevertheless, as others say, if it changes dynamically, probably an enum is not the right choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be possible to create an `Enum` at runtime using [EnumBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.enumbuilder%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from your database values, it would not be of any value at compile time.

See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MappingDotNetEnumerations.aspx) article on an alternative.